# ASA 5505 + cannot login to ASDM

Tags: firewall, cisco, asa

I've got a Cisco ASA 5505 with ASA 9.1(3) and ASDM 7.1(4), and have done the factory reset described here

https://staff.washington.edu/curreri/restoring-factory-defaults-to-the-cisco-asa5505-firewall-via-the-console/

and successfully reset the enable password, but cannot login successfully to ASDM.

In ASDM I've left the username blank and tried using the enable password in the password field, but no luck!

Ideas, suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Dan

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out:

```
ciscoasa(config) # username admin password cisco privilege 15
```